# When using arrayUnion to add element to arrayField in firestore, i get TypeError default.collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im making an app using ReactJs with firebase. In updatePlayers, i followed the firebase documentation exactly to add elements to an array. In firestore, i have a collection called footballgames with a document of a game called C3j5hXxNFKMBUM7YxaNX. It contains an array field which contains an array of players and i would like to add "John" to the array whenever the function is called. However i keep getting the error 
TypeError: _firebase_firebase_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.collection is not a function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import GameDetails from "../../components/game-details/game-details.component";
import PlayerList from "../../components/player-list/player-list.component";
import firestore from '../../firebase/firebase.utils'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

class GameDetailPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: "",
    };
  }


  updatePlayers=()=>{
    var playersRef=firestore.collection("footballgames").doc("C3j5hXxNFKMBUM7YxaNX")
    playersRef.update({
      Players:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("John")
    })
  }



  render() {
    const { games, currentUser } = this.props;
    let { linkUrl } = this.props.match.params;
    const gameObj = games[linkUrl];
    console.log("user", currentUser);


    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="game-list">
          <GameDetails game={gameObj} />
        </div>
        <h2>Current players</h2>
        {currentUser ? (
          <div className="player-list">
            {gameObj.Players.map((player, index) => (
              <PlayerList key={index} player={player} />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Loading</p>
        )}
        <button onClick={()=>this.updatePlayers()}>Join</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  games: state.games.games,
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameDetailPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with arrayUnion. Using what you're showing here, it seems that this is not working (the method collection is not found):

```
var playersRef = firestore.collection(...)
```

You'll want to use this instead to find the collection method:

```
var playersRef = firebase.firestore.collection(...)
```

Your import is pulling something else in and calling it `firestore`, and it's probably not the same as `firebase.firestore`:

```
import firestore from '../../firebase/firebase.utils'
```